# priority of newly constructed thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I create a new thread like this:

```
Runnable r=new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // content
    }
  }
  Thread th = new Thread();
  th.start(r);
```

What is the priority of the newly constructed thread?

Comment: It is worth noting that the priority is a hint to the OS which may not be honoured and often doesn't do much in practical terms even when it is available.

Comment: @  Peter Lawrey  what do you mean by `hint to OS`?

Comment: he means that the OS may choose to ignore whatever priority you ask for.

Comment: @ Stephen C then i suppose there is no need to set priorities.Is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when a new Thread is constructed,it runs at the same priority as the thread that constructed
it.Most new threads are constructed directly or indirectly by the main thread and will therefore run
at priority of 5.This works well under many scenarios,but there are times when you will want to 
raise or lower a thread's priority.
you can determine the current priority by calling `getPriority()` on the thread whose priority you want
to check.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> When code running in some thread
>   creates a new Thread object, the new
>   thread has its priority initially set
>   equal to the priority of the creating
>   thread, and is a daemon thread if and
>   only if the creating thread is a
>   daemon.

However, you may set the priority, using [setPriority()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> When code running in some thread creates a new Thread object, the new thread has
>   its priority initially set equal to the priority of the creating thread (...)